# How to use QSettings to save a variable

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to save a variable state with QSettings and then recall this value at the boot up portion of my program. This is the code I have now with the first portion in the SetupUi part of my program. The void function is called with a button press. Currently the 2000 is the only one that is passed through. Either I am not saving the file or I am not recalling it correctly.

```
 QSettings settings(QString("configs/config.ini"),QSettings::IniFormat);
cuttime2= (settings.value("cuttime2s/config/key",2000)).toFloat();

void Application::saveSettings()
{
QSettings settings(QString("configs/config.ini"),QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.value("cuttime2s/config/key",cuttime2).toFloat();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `setValue` method when you are saving the value. The `value` method is used to read from QSettings, not to save.

Comment: Thank you for your help.